# Is there a way for mod_wsgi/Flask and mod_dav to coexist?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, webdav

I'm working on a website that's basically a file repository for a bunch of data.

I need people to be able to traverse the directories and download files both via WebDAV and their browser (i.e. mod_autoindex).

This works fine using just mod_autoindex and mod_dav. But I wanted to use mod_wsgi/Flask to customize and serve the directory listing pages instead of the fairly inflexible mod_autoindex, using the Flask-AutoIndex plugin.

The problem is that this seems to then interfere with the DAV requests. I get a `The URL contains extraneous path components. The resource could not be identified.` errors when I try to connect with a DAV client.

Is there a way I can make mod_wsgi ignore all requests with WebDAV-specific headers so that they can be handled correctly by mod_dav?

EDIT:

Here's my Apache config:

`LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
DavLockDB "/var/lib/urs_test/dav/DavLock"
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /urs_test/webdav_info /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/urs_test/app.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess test processes=2 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup test`

`<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/urs_test>
AuthType UrsOAuth2
require valid-user
Dav On
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>`

ANOTHER EDIT:

So I think I've figured out what's up here. It has to do with the WSGIScriptAlias tag, which is being appended to the request path.

A WebDAV request for `/urs_test/files` is modified to `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/urs_test/app.wsgi/files` by the time it reaches mod_dav.

So I need to figure out a way to selectively apply that alias directive to certain HTTP methods (i.e. PROPFIND) and not to others (i.e. GET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came back to this a while later, and I've found something that appears to work.

Basically, I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect requests that I don't want mod_wsgi/Flask to handle.

So, if my Flask app is being served under `/endpoint`, and I want my WebDAV repo to be available under `/endpoint/dav`, my config is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/endpoint/dav
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PROPFIND|OPTIONS|PROPPATCH)$
RewriteRule ^/endpoint/dav /local_path_to_dav_repo/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/endpoint/dav
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteCond /local_path_to_dav_repo/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^/endpoint/dav(.*) /local_path_to_dav_repo/$1 [L]

WSGIScriptAlias /endpoint /my_wsgi_dir/flask.wsgi

<Directory /local_path_to_dav_repo>
Dav On
</Directory>
```

The first 3 lines grab any DAV-specific method (the read-only ones, for now) and redirect them to the local path of the DAV repo. Because `mod_wsgi` is only grabbing requests for the `/endpoint` URI, this request never reaches Flask and goes straight to `mod_dav`.

The next 4 lines grab any `GET` requests for specific files and redirect them to the specific location of that file in the local filesystem. Once again, this request doesn't reach Flask. From what I understand, it's faster to have Apache serve the file directly than to have Flask do it.

So the result is that only `GET` requests for directories in the DAV repo make it to `mod_wsgi`, so I can build a nice-looking directory index and serve it via Flask.